# error in Where clause with multiple OR conditions

Tags: sql

Why does the query below not work? I need to get data for each of the following numbers:

```
select * 
from dbo.BAS_GDW_TMO_PARCEL_EBILL_ALL_ARCHIVE_AUDIT_RESULT_TBL
where TMO_TRACK_NBR in (964855234, 141329655, 138150364, '3F3857')
```

Comment: seems good to me, are you receiving any error? Can you put the content of your table with column names? And which dbms r u using?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message you get. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Is `TMO_TRACK_NBR` a numeric or character field?  You are mixing numeric/character values in your IN clause.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Can you also try TMO_TRACK_NBR in ('964855234', '141329655', '138150364', '3F3857')

Comment: Try to put all values in quotes like the last one.

Comment: sorry it works now with quotes, i used the wrong colom!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing types in the `IN`.  An `IN` list supports values of only one type.  If you mix strings and numbers, then the strings are converted to numbers.  And you get an error because the string does not represent a valid number.

Don't mix types.  Use the appropriate type for comparisons.  If `TMO_TRACK_NBR` is a string, use strings for all the values:

```
select * 
from dbo.BAS_GDW_TMO_PARCEL_EBILL_ALL_ARCHIVE_AUDIT_RESULT_TBL
where TMO_TRACK_NBR in ('964855234', '141329655', '138150364', '3F3857');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to hte SQL IN documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql

*Is a list of expressions to test for a match. **All expressions must be of the same type as test_expression**.*

You are testing integer values (964855234) and string ( '3F3857' ) in the `IN` clause.

You have to check wich datatype is the TMO_TRACK_NBR  column and test data with the right datatype

Answer (score 0):

All the data in the in clause should be of the same type

So it should be either this

```
select * 
from dbo.BAS_GDW_TMO_PARCEL_EBILL_ALL_ARCHIVE_AUDIT_RESULT_TBL
where TMO_TRACK_NBR in ('964855234', '141329655', '138150364', '3F3857')
```

or this

```
select * 
from dbo.BAS_GDW_TMO_PARCEL_EBILL_ALL_ARCHIVE_AUDIT_RESULT_TBL
where TMO_TRACK_NBR in (964855234, 141329655, 138150364, 3F3857)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the TMO_TRACK_NBR can contain an F it tells me its not an INT.
If you don't put the quotes around the other numbers as well the IN operation will try to convert them all to INT (including the '3F3857').

```
select * 
from dbo.BAS_GDW_TMO_PARCEL_EBILL_ALL_ARCHIVE_AUDIT_RESULT_TBL 
where TMO_TRACK_NBR in ('964855234', '141329655', '138150364', '3F3857')
```

Next time placing the error should be good to.
I think you got:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3F3857' to data type int.
```

Answer (score 0):

Definetely, the reaseon is that you use data of two types in your condition.

```
    select * 
    from dbo.BAS_GDW_TMO_PARCEL_EBILL_ALL_ARCHIVE_AUDIT_RESULT_TBL
    where TMO_TRACK_NBR in (
964855234 --int
, 141329655 --int
, 138150364 --int
, '3F3857' --varchar
)
```

Just make it like this:

```
select * 
from dbo.BAS_GDW_TMO_PARCEL_EBILL_ALL_ARCHIVE_AUDIT_RESULT_TBL
where TMO_TRACK_NBR in (
'964855234' --varchar
, '141329655' --varchar
, '138150364' --varchar
, '3F3857' --varchar
)
```